# Dual Booting issues, windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, dual-boot

Okay, so I've been trying to Dual Boot My computer. I already installed Windows 7, and now i want to install Ubuntu, but when i load to the disk, goes the purple screen, i select the language, and then install ubuntu, after this is the problem. It either goes a black screen with flashing cusor for awhile before freezing, or goes the ubuntu loading screen the freezes after awhile. Now I've tried making a new disc and partions, and still have the samething happening. I've recently built this computer, it has i5 processor, 8gb ram, and a TB hard drive. So if any suggesting would be very helpful, because i've read every thing my CompTIA book has to offer, muiltiple thread, and nothing i've tried has worked.

Comment: As [user139428](http://askubuntu.com/users/139428/user139428) asked: *What type of computer is it? Have you disable the UEFI firmware and fast boot?*

Comment: I built the computer

Comment: What motherboard does it have? Have you tried disabling UEFI firmware and fast boot? Are you able to do so?

Comment: ASrock b75  pro3-m and no i can not

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'disk', are you referring to a manufactured installation CD that you ordered online or purchased at a store, or a CD you made yourself by downloading an iso and burning it to the disk? If the latter is true, you may have gotten a bad download (as uncommon as it seems, trust me, it happens to all of us).

In addition to this, I generally recommend *against* using physical disks when installing Ubuntu (I have had some mess-ups when doing so myself); I have found one of the most reliable tool to use when installing more widely used distros (like Ubuntu & Mint) is **Linux Live USB** (Or LiLi, for short; [link](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)). It puts the image onto a flash drive, as opposed to a disk, so any 1GB flash drive will generally do. All of this, of course, is optional, and CDs may work fine for you, so I advise to redownload the iso before trying it on a flash drive.

To check for iso file corruption, as well, you can use **md5sum**. I would just google it, as it's a bit easier to explain without words.

Comment: I've created two discs, and tried a flash drive and same issue

Comment: So tried the md5sum, and the file is fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues as well, when I did this, but eventually found this page: [WindowsDualBoot: Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) I hope it helps you, as it helped me greatly.

I also used a USB and when I tried installing it via restart it wouldn't work, however, I went into it the USB's files in windows, found the installer, and used it that way, and installed it on my pre-prepared linux partition.

Comment: I've looked at that page, but can you explain more on that second part?

Comment: I opened the USB via My Computer < The drive the USB was in (which was my E) and found the wubi installer and installed it what way.